# Creating a build configuration in TeamCity using Powershell

Tags: powershell, teamcity

Anyone know how I can create or delete a build configuration in TeamCity, only using Powershell?  I am trying to automate our entire project setup process; have looked at the REST API but that appears to be mostly read-only.

Answer (score 2):

There is no ability to automate creation of build configuration. Watch/vote for corresponding feature request JetBrains tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-7999.

Answer (score 1):

Teamcity [8.x REST](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildConfigurationAndTemplateSettings) provides the ability to create build configuration. You can use something like below to utilize to REST API.

```
function Create-Build{
    param
    (           
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $buildName, 

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $parentProjectId
    )

    # Create Teamcity URL
    $url = "http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/projects/$parentProjectId/buildTypes"

    $webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $webRequest.ContentType = "text/plain"
    $PostStr = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($buildName)
    $webrequest.ContentLength = $PostStr.Length
    $webRequest.Method = "POST"
    $webRequest.Accept = "*/*"
    $webRequest.Credentials = new-object system.net.networkcredential("teamcityuser", "password")

    $requestStream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream()
    $requestStream.Write($PostStr, 0,$PostStr.length)
    $requestStream.Close()

    [System.Net.WebResponse] $resp = $webRequest.GetResponse();
    $rs = $resp.GetResponseStream();
    [System.IO.StreamReader] $sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -argumentList $rs;
    [string] $results = $sr.ReadToEnd();

    $results
}

# Call ps function to create build configuration
Create-Build -buildName "CopiedBuild" -parentProjectId "TestProject"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [psake](http://github.com/JamesKovacs/psake/)? It's a build automation tool and somebody integrated some TeamCity support (in [teamcity.ps1](http://github.com/JamesKovacs/psake/blob/master/teamcity.ps1)).

Comment: I have looked at psake.  Unfortunately, its integration with TeamCity is either read-only or updating existing build types.  I am looking to create a new build type (configuration) somehow without using the TeamCity Web UI.